# Is it possible to exclude (filter out) events from the Mod Event Socket telnet client output?

Tags: freeswitch

[Mod Event Socket](http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Mod_event_socket) provides a useful [telnet client](http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Mod_event_socket#Telnet_Client).  I can [filter](http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Mod_event_socket#filter) specific events and keep track of just these, but I can't find how to exclude events I *don't* want to monitor (typically `HEARTBEAT` and `RE_SCHEDULE`). Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Just use [nixevent](https://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Event_Socket#nixevent):

```
nixevent HEARTBEAT

nixevent RE_SCHEDULE
```

Everytime you type one of the above lines followed by two line breaks, it should respond with this:

```
Content-Type: command/reply
Reply-Text: +OK events nixed
```